# How to extract polygons from raster?

Tags: vector, raster, qgis

The goal is to get the vector polygons from raster areas accordingly to their gray scale. For example:

- Dark pixels to dark_relief.shp
- Gray pixels to gray_relief.shp
- Light pixels to light_relief.shp

First I got GeoTIFF from SRTM file using Raster – Analysis – DEM (Terrain models) in Hillshade mode:

[image]

Then I use Raster - Conversion - Polygonize (Raster to Vector), but result is too many small polygons. Obviously I should prepare the image before a conversion.

Any hints what to do?
May be other right way exists?

Regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the cut off points for each contour/band/classification you can reclassify your raster file in qGIS with the raster calculator. From there you can use raster to vector to create polygons only for the contours/bands/classifications you specified.

The example raster calculator calculation below should divide a layer into three pieces, areas below 1000, areas between 1000 and 1200, and areas above 1200.

```
("layer" > 1000) * 1 + ("layer" > 1200) * 1
```

With a starting raster of:

[image]

And the above calculation, I got:

[image]

Which will polygonize pretty easily and cleanly.